# Java splitting a string while ignoring any delimiters between brackets

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split

I'm looking for java regex to split the inputString while ignoring delimiters between brackets/multiple brackets.

Java code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[,regex?]");
String[] desiredOutput =p.split(inputString);
```

for example:

```
inputString="1,{2,{3},4},{4,5},6";
```

desiredOutput with ; delimiter:

```
1;{2,{3},4};{4,5};6
```

Thnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible using regular expressions.

The expression would have to match strings with balanced brackets. (Which is not a regular language.)

You need to use some other parsing technique or do it manually by counting `{` and `}`.

Comment: 1+ This needs to be made into a "sticky" post or an FAQ, since it gets asked so many times, but usually in the context of a CSV or the parsing of a mathematical expression.

Comment: More precisely, it's not possible with Java's regular expressions. .NET or Perl have no problem with recursive regexes.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, right. So if this question was tagged Perl, would you think regular expressions would be a suitable tool? (honest question :-)

Comment: @TimPietzcker @aioobe basically, this kind of expression does not fit into the definition of `Regular Grammar`, therefore regular expressions are not the right tool to be used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

Comment: @Max, I think both Tim and I understand that ;-)

Comment: @aioobe Meh, I never get a good chance to show off my intellect :P

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help! I will try to find another solution.