# java - split string according to delimiter but only outside parenthesis?

Tags: java, string

I want to split string according to delimiter but only outside parenthesis.
Is there any library (built-in or not) that does so?
Example:
If delimiter is ":" then:
string "a:b:c" should be split to "a","b","c"
string "a(b:c):d" should be split to "a(b:c)","d"

Thanks

Comment: I've answered a similar question over here:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as

Comment: ...and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656212/java-splitting-a-string-while-ignoring-any-delimiters-between-brackets

Comment: so your answer is that it can't be done using regular expressions? Then how can it be done? I can parse it manually but prefer something that is ready and tested :)

Comment: I'm saying it depends on how you want to for instance treat `"a(b:(c:d)):e"`. In general, I would strongly advice you to use a parser generator.

Comment: a nice spitter is that one provided by google guava libraries, you can check it out here:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter

Answer (score 0):

The other commenters are right that you are probably best off using a grammar library. If, however, this is a one off thing and you'd rather just deal with it quickly, this algorithm should handle it in a clear fashion, and will deal with nested parentheses. Note: I'm assuming your parentheses are well balanced, i.e., no right parentheses that don't have an opening left paren before them.

```
int parenDepth = 0;
int start = 0;
List<String> splits = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    char ch = str.get(i);
    if(ch == '(')
         parenDepth++;
    else if(ch == ')')
         parenDepth--;
    else if(parenDepth == 0 && ch ==',')
    {
         if(start != i) // comment out this if if you want to allow empty strings in 
                        // the splits
             splits.add(str.substring(start, i));
         start = i+1;
    }
}

splits.add(str.substring(start));
```

Comment: You forgot to add the last element, but seems like nice straight forward approach

Comment: Oops, fixed it to add that one too. Thanks!