# Split string in with some comma separators

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split next string

```
value1,value2[2,5],value3[4,7],value4,value5[7,4]
```

After split i should have next array:

```
value1
value2[2,5]
value3[4,7]
value4
value5[7,4]
```

I can't split on comma, and I don't want complicate logic to much.
I would like to have simplest logic for this.

Thanks for help.

edit:
my attempt:

```
  var parts = Regex.Split(line, "/([^,]+\\[[^,\\]]*\\,[^,\\]]*\\])|([^,]+)|(,,)/g");
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to answer your question. Please show what you attempted first. Splitting with `,` would never work here.

Comment: is it always `value` with a number at the end? or is this just an example and there could be any string?

Comment: no, does not have to be number.

Comment: but always `value`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792931/java-regex-split-comma-separated-list-but-exclude-commas-within-parentheses, replace `(` with `[` and `\(` with `\[`. Oh, you added your effort, great. .NET regex does not support regex delimiters and `/g` modifier. Can the brackets be nested? Like `value1,value2[2,[56,78]]`?

Comment: Look here, your regex works - `(?<val>[^,]+\[[^,\]]*,[^,\]]*])|(?<val>[^,]+)|(,,)`, I only added the named captures. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b%5c%5b%5b%5e%2c%5c%5d%5d*%2c%5b%5e%2c%5c%5d%5d*%5d)%7c(%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b)%7c(%2c%2c)&i=value1%2cvalue2%5b2%2c5%5d%2cvalue3%5b4%2c7%5d%2cvalue4%2cvalue5%5b7%2c4%5d). No idea why you use `(,,)`

Comment: I'd use: [`[^][,]+(?:\[[^][]*])?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5d%5b%2c%5d%2b(%3f%3a%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d)%3f&i=value1%2cvalue2%5b2%2c5%5d%2cvalue3%5b4%2c7%5d%2cvalue4%2cvalue5%5b7%2c4%5d) to *match* these values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split on `,(?!\d+])`:

```
string st = @"value1,value2[21,5],value3[4,7],value4,value5[7,4]";
var output = Regex.Split(st, @",(?!\d+])").ToList();
```

Which will output:

```
value1
value2[2,5]
value3[4,7]
value4
value5[7,4]
```

Comment: `.RemoveAll(s => s == ",");` is redundant, just remove the capturing group around `,`. And a note: this won't work if `[...]` can be nested. Also, technically, this still allows splitting with a comma that is not *inside* `[...]` as you only check for a *closing* `]`, not if the comma is preceded wtih a `[`. *Matching* approach would be most appropriate here (IMHO).

Comment: You can get expected result without removing ",". Replace "(,)(?!\d+])" by ",(?!\d+])"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks once again. I wasn't aware that the capturing group would keep the captured value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string input = "value1,value2[2,5],value3[4,7],value4,value5[7,4]";
string pattern = @"(?'value'\w+\d+),?|(?'value'\w+\d+\[\d+,\d+\]),?";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that splitting here is the wrong approach and it would be easier to understand and maintain if you were to match against the items you're searching for rather than split against commas. As such you could:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = 
    Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+\d+(\[\d+,\d+\])?").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
```